# wordpress wpcf7 - get form value in message body

Tags: wordpress

I have integrated wordpress contact form 7. I have to get form value in message body so that recipient see what exactly user submits the value in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're editing the form, go to the "Mail" tab and below you should see the available field values that can be copied and pasted into your message body a few fields below. There should be a row like below:

```
[your-name] [your-surname] [your-email]
```

If you highlight any of those and paste them into the "Message Body", the value that a customer inputs on the frontend should come through to the recipient.

[image]

Comment: Its works!!! my next target is, there should be content before that tag. for eg - Customer Name [FullName] like wise.